# pasting files in unix

Tags: text-processing, scripting, paste

I have a folder with multiple files:

```
W1747_RH_sig_window_outliers_g_chrom
W1747_RH_sig_window_outliers_g_pos
W1747_RH_sig_window_snps_g_chrom
W1747_RH_sig_window_snps_g_pos
W19173_RH_sig_window_outliers_g_chrom
W19173_RH_sig_window_outliers_g_pos
```

`W1747_RH_sig_window_outliers_g_chrom` and `W1747_RH_sig_window_outliers_g_pos` both corrspond to a single file `W1747_RH_sig_window_outliers_g` or `W1747_RH_sig_window_snps_g_chrom` and `W1747_RH_sig_window_snps_g_pos` both correspond to `W1747_RH_sig_window_snps`  I want to paste them

```
paste W1747_RH_sig_window_outliers_g_chrom W1747_RH_sig_window_outliers_g_pos > W1747_RH_sig_window_outliers_vcf. txt
paste W1747_RH_sig_window_snps_g_chrom W1747_RH_sig_window_snps_g_pos > W1747_RH_sig_window_snps_vcf.txt
```

However as there are more than 200 files it is difficult for me to do it like that, Is there any easier way to do it for instance by running through a loop?

Comment: you meant *file with multiple **lines***? Post the expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With POSIX shells:

```
for file in *_g_chrom; do
  base=${file%_g_chrom}
  paste -- "$file" "${base}_g_pos" > "${base}_vcf.txt"
done
```